# Cross compile chromium for arm linux

Tags: linux, arm, chromium

I'm trying to cross compile chromium source code (**280796 revision**) for **ARM Linux** on **ubuntu 14.04** and get this error:

```
/third_party/pdfium/core/src/fxcrt/fx_extension.cpp:12:17: fatal error: \
                     ctime: No such file or directory
 #include <ctime>
```

Comment: You have omitted too much information.  It can not find the header file.  You maybe compiling C++ source as 'C' for instance.  A little investigation shows `ctime` is `time.h`.  You didn't try very much to resolve your issue.

Comment: how can I do that ? i just followed a tutorial to cross compile and I'm new to chromium developpement her the link for the tuto :https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxChromiumArm  , i did some investigation and i found that the problem came from cflags : --sysroot=/workspace/chromium/src/arm-sysroot

Answer (score 0):

You need to install development packages in order to have these headers. For Opensuse for example you would need the file `/usr/include/time.h` which is included in

```
glibc-devel
```

but there might be other files you are missing...

Comment: I already have this file in my system ? the problem is that the arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ compilet is looking for this file in the  --sysroot=/workspace/chromium/src/arm-sysroot

Comment: I already have this file in my system !! as i said before the problem is that the arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ compiler is looking for this file inside --sysroot=chromium/src/arm-sysroot , her an example of command line : arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -Igen -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-parameter -pipe -fPIC -march=armv7-a -mtune=generic-armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb --sysroot=/chromium/src/arm-sysroot -O0 -g -std=gnu++11 -c third_party/pdfium/core/src/fxcrt/fx_extension.cpp

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176794/how-do-i-cross-compile-chromium-for-arm) to validate your workflow, and make sure that you are doing the right thing